Error when initializing tf2_ros::buffer in ROS2 Foxy
does anyone know why i cant initialize an instance of tf2_ros::buffer in ROS2 Foxy?
test_file.cpp :
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"
#include "tf2_ros/buffer.h"
#include "tf2/convert.h"
#include "tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    tf2_ros::Buffer buffer;

}

CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(test_package)

# Default to C99
if(NOT CMAKE_C_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
endif()

# Default to C++14
if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

# find dependencies
find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rclcpp REQUIRED) 
find_package(tf2_ros REQUIRED)
find_package(tf2 REQUIRED)
find_package(geometry_msgs REQUIRED)
# uncomment the following section in order to fill in
# further dependencies manually.
# find_package(<dependency> REQUIRED)
add_executable(test_package src/test_file.cpp)

include_directories(include)
include_directories(
  ${tf2_ros_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

ament_target_dependencies(test_package
tf2_ros
tf2
geometry_msgs
)

if(BUILD_TESTING)
  find_package(ament_lint_auto REQUIRED)
  # the following line skips the linter which checks for copyrights
  # uncomment the line when a copyright and license is not present in all source files
  #set(ament_cmake_copyright_FOUND TRUE)
  # the following line skips cpplint (only works in a git repo)
  # uncomment the line when this package is not in a git repo
  #set(ament_cmake_cpplint_FOUND TRUE)
  ament_lint_auto_find_test_dependencies()
endif()

ament_package()


package.xml:
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://download.ros.org/schema/package_format3.xsd" schematypens="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"?>
<package format="3">
  <name>test_package</name>
  <version>0.0.0</version>
  <description>TODO: Package description</description>
  <maintainer email="bryan@todo.todo">bryan</maintainer>
  <license>TODO: License declaration</license>

  <buildtool_depend>ament_cmake</buildtool_depend>
  
  <depend>tf2</depend>
  <depend>tf2_ros</depend>
  <depend>rclcpp</depend>
  <depend>geometry_msgs</depend>


  <test_depend>ament_lint_auto</test_depend>
  <test_depend>ament_lint_common</test_depend>

  <export>
    <build_type>ament_cmake</build_type>
  </export>
</package>


I'm getting the following error:
error: no matching function for call to ‘tf2_ros::Buffer::Buffer()’
    9 |     tf2_ros::Buffer buffer;

Thank you very much !

The error you get is that there are no constructor of tf2_ros::Buffer without argument (e.g. tf2_ros::Buffer::Buffer()).
This constructor needs a clock, hence an underlying Node:
auto node{std::make_shared<rclcpp::Node>("node_name")};
tf2_ros::Buffer buffer(node->get_clock());


Thank you @oKermorgant that solved it!
